# What is the probability of a string GUID's hashcode being odd or even?

Tags: java, guid, probability, hashcode

The GUID is a 23-character string that is unique across JVMs, machines, threads, processes, etc.
Its hashcode is computed as per the Java String hashcode definition:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29

How can I compute the probability of the hashcode being odd, or being even?

Answer (score 1):

`31^x` is odd for all `x`, so the only bit which can change the oddness/eveness of each term is `s[i]`. So you would need to know `s[i]` for each term as changing just one of these from odd to even will change the oddness/even-ness of the result. So I think the minimal calculation would be:

```
s[0] + ... + s[n-1] // if odd, the hash will be odd, if even the hash will be even
```

*edit* just re-read your question, and realise what you ask for is the probability. The probability is 50/50 (assuming 50% of the characters in the character-set correspond to even integers). No information about the string will help you get a better probabilistic estimate as the odd-ness/even-ness is too sensitive to changing individual terms.